# What is the best way to store and use information between two objects in python?

Tags: python, database, numpy, pandas, hdf

I have a set of names/id of objects (in terms of the objects in life, not python objects).

For simplicity, these objects have the following names:

```
A, B, C, D, E ...
```

The number of such objects about 2000 (and in future can be about 6000).

I am trying to determine the best way to accomplish task: **what is the best way to store information (param1, param2, ..., paramN) between each pair of objects**. Look like as following data structure:

```
                A               B              C              D 
A             -          [param1, param2] [param1, param2] [param1, param2]

B      [param1, param2]        -          [param1, param2] [param1, param2]

C      [param1, param2]  [param1, param2]       -          [param1, param2]

D      [param1, param2]  [param1, param2] [param1, param2]        -
```

**It is important to take into account several aspects:**

- cell[A,B]=cell[B,A] so we need to store just 1/2 of all table
- I need to save this table in tmp dir and load in start of my python application
- I need to quickly extract value from this table in my python application

My solution:
I used the pandas.DataFrame module.
And for each parameters: *param1, param2, ...* I make individual triangular tables: *param1table, param2table, ...* After filling I save them in the CSV files: *param1table.csv, param2table.csv, ....csv*

In my program if I need to param1 in pairs: A, B, I need to load *param1table.csv* (pandas.read_csv) and see if value [A,B] exists return it, else return [B,A]

I think its not effective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with `pd.DataFrame`, you could use a `MultiIindex` ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)) with `Object_1`, `Object_2` as `index` and `Param_1`, `Param_2` as `columns`. This would be preferable because `DataFrame` isn't designed for storing `list` objects.

You could use `np.triu` to extract the upper triangle of your current `DataFrame`, (returns the lower triangle zeroed out), use `.replace(0, np.nan)` and `.stack()` to convert to long form. From there just need to `reset_index()`, and `.split()` the `list` objects using `df.col.str.split(','), expand=True`.

You could easily make sure that you only store `Object_1`, `Object_2` but not `Object_2`, `Object_1`, and access your params using `df.loc[('Object_1', 'Object_2'), :]`.

You can store the result in `.csv` or `hdf`, which would be a bit quicker ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables)) for `n * (n-1) / 2` rows.

To illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
from itertools import permutations
```

Starting with a simple `DataFrame` that looks similar to the one you seem to be using currently:

```
objs = [o for o in permutations(list(string.ascii_uppercase[:5]), 2)]
obj_1, obj_2 = zip(*objs)
params = [list(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=2)) for j in range(len(objs))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'obj_1': obj_1, 'obj_2': obj_2, 'params': params})
df = df.set_index(['obj_1', 'obj_2']).unstack()

obj_2       A       B       C       D       E
obj_1                                        
A        None  [4, 7]  [7, 5]  [0, 5]  [3, 0]
B      [4, 6]    None  [0, 8]  [0, 7]  [7, 2]
C      [6, 9]  [6, 2]    None  [7, 8]  [3, 1]
D      [0, 0]  [2, 4]  [9, 8]    None  [1, 8]
E      [2, 3]  [8, 6]  [5, 7]  [5, 8]    None
```

Assuming the `params` are symmetric, let's get rid of the lower triangle:

```
mask = np.ones(df.shape,dtype='bool')
mask[np.tril_indices(len(df))] = False
df = df.where(mask)

obj_2      A       B       C       D       E
obj_1                                       
A        NaN  [4, 7]  [7, 5]  [0, 5]  [3, 0]
B        NaN     NaN  [0, 8]  [0, 7]  [7, 2]
C        NaN     NaN     NaN  [7, 8]  [3, 1]
D        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  [1, 8]
E        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Next convert to long form and extract `params` from `list`:

```
df = df.stack()
df['param_1'], df['param_2'] = (zip(*df.params))

             params  param_1  param_2
obj_1 obj_2                          
A     B      [4, 7]        4        7
      C      [7, 5]        7        5
      D      [0, 5]        0        5
      E      [3, 0]        3        0
B     C      [0, 8]        0        8
      D      [0, 7]        0        7
      E      [7, 2]        7        2
C     D      [7, 8]        7        8
      E      [3, 1]        3        1
D     E      [1, 8]        1        8
```

So we don't need `params` anymore:

```
df.drop('params', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And can now access like so:

```
df.loc[('B', 'C')]

param_1    0
param_2    8
```

Or individually:

```
df.loc[('B', 'C'), 'param_1']

0
```

Comment: I have a list of names of objects = [Object_1, Object_2, Object_3], I need to access between all pairs of this list (e.g, [Object_1,[Object_2][param1], [Object_1,[Object_3][param1], [Object_2,[Object_1][param2]). How to do this using MultiIndex?

Comment: df.loc[('B', 'C')] is okay, but for df.loc[('C', 'B')] is key error. So I need to write some function to access for ['C', 'B'] that return ['B','C'] right?

Comment: Depends, you could also set if up (by sorting `columns` and `index` before `.stack()`  so that the first key (`obj_1`) is always 'smaller' than the second key, as in the example. If that doesn't work, a simple `try:.. except KeyError:` would also deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

From my ML and Data Science experience there're two common ways to share data between python scripts: CSV and [HDF5](http://www.h5py.org/). If csv is mostly fine for you, stay with it as long as possible, because HDF5 doesn't work well with non-integer values.

If you have some problems with your disk capacity simply zip your data.
Pandas'  `read_csv()` understands most popular compression algorithms marvelously.

If there're speed issues on load — chunk it and then categorize it.

Also if your data is 'mirrored' why not simply name-order your columns and then recall it in a right way? E.G.: call(cell[B,A]) -> call(cell[A,B]) -> cell[B,A].

**Addition:** For some extreme cases you could save each row separately (don't forget to cut the empty part of it), and later create some sort of cache buffer for the most popular calls.